# How to set network proxy for Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.0 7?

Tags: networking, proxy, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I've already found this [guide](http://www.mobile88.ph/news/read.asp?file=/2011/8/9/20110809114143&phone=Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-10.1-tips-tricks-setting-up-proxy). It's for the Galaxy 10.1 though and my unit doesn't have the Wi-Fi settings option. Or at least I can't find it.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My apologies, I just found [it](http://www.cantoni.org/2012/02/20/galaxy-tab-http-proxy-settings). For the benefit of those who have the same problem:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It should apply to the other Galaxy Tab 2 models, too.